# Counter keeps repeating please provide answer

Tags: c++, c, timer, clock, countdown

Now, I am learning C programming, I stumbled upon a countdown code on 'Codeproject.com' and decided to run it and analyse it to learn. However, the output Countdown repeats each number thousands of times before moving to the next. Please I need help understanding why this is. The code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
      unsigned int x_hours = 0;  
      unsigned int x_minutes = 0;
      unsigned int x_seconds = 0;
      unsigned int x_milliseconds = 0;
      unsigned int totaltime = 0, count_down_time_in_secs = 0, time_left=0;

      clock_t x_startTime, x_countTime;
      count_down_time_in_secs = 10; // 1 min is 60

      x_startTime = clock();
      time_left = count_down_time_in_secs-x_seconds;  //update timer

      while (time_left>0)
      {
        x_countTime = clock();
        x_milliseconds = x_countTime-x_startTime;
        x_seconds=(x_milliseconds/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))-(x_hours*60);
        x_minutes=(x_milliseconds/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))/60;
        x_hours=x_minutes/60;


        time_left = count_down_time_in_secs-x_seconds; 

        printf("\nyou have %d seconds left", time_left, count_down_time_in_secs);
      }

      printf("\n\n\nTime's out\n\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a line to print out x_milliseconds inside your loop and it will become obvious what is happening. i.e. you are executing your loop thousands of times a second.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are fast, so the loop will execute many times per second. You need to store the previous time, compare it with the current time and only print it if it changes.

Also your `printf()` call has only one `%d` placeholder but you are passing two parameters to it.